# POST received from HttpListener

Tags: c#, http

I have a question:
I am using a HttpListener and have the following code snippet:

```
while (is_active) 
        {   
            HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext ();
            Debug.Log (ctx.Request.HttpMethod);
        }
```

As I understand everytime the listener gets a new request the listener.GetContext() function gives back that request. This works fine when receiving A GET. Then my Debug log gets called only once, but when I receive a POST my Debug Log gets called 4 times: one time saying that a POST came and 3 times saying that a GET came.
Does anyone know a solution for it and why this happens?
Cheers,
          Elisabeth

Comment: Can you edit your log to include the request data/path?

Comment: Probably, those exact requests hit your listener. Use Fiddler to intercept them.

Comment: Hi! When I output the ctx.Request.Query string it gives me the following.    When sending a POST my Debug.Log tells me that I get 4 calls. One call is a POST with the Query string System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection and 3 calls are a GET with the following Query string after the ip adress: favicon.ico What does this mean? What are Fiddler and how can I use them?

Comment: Ok I just ignore now the favicon.icon requests, but is there also a possiblity to thell the Httplistener that it should ignore this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there are more requests incoming than you expect. This was confirmed in the comments.

Use Fiddler to inspect what exact requests are coming in.

The way to deal with requests that you don't want to handle is to

1. detect them (possibly using the URL or the HTTP method)
2. and send an error status code back (like 404).

> is there also a possiblity to thell the Httplistener that it should ignore this request?

There is no way to do that and there is no need. Simply teach *your code* to ignore the requests.